# Improve XML readability in Oracle 11g for binary XMLType storage for huge files

Tags: xml, oracle11g, xquery, xmltype

I have one requirement in which I have to process huge XML files. That means there might be around 1000 xml files and the whole size of these files would be around 2GB.

What I need is to store all the data in these files to my Oracle DB. For this I have used sqlloader for bulk uploading of all my XML files to my DB and it is stored as binary XMLTYPE in my database.Now I need to query these files and store the data in relational tables.For this I have used XMLTable Xpath queries. Everything is fine when I try to query single xml file within my DB. But if it is trying to query all those files it is taking too much time which is not acceptable.

Here's my one sample xml content:

```
 <ABCD>
  <EMPLOYEE id="11" date="25-Apr-1983"> 
    <NameDetails> 
      <Name NameType="a"> 
        <NameValue> 
          <FirstName>ABCD</FirstName> 
          <Surname>PQR</Surname> 
          <OriginalName>TEST1</OriginalName> 
          <OriginalName>TEST2</OriginalName> 
        </NameValue> 
      </Name> 
      <Name NameType="b"> 
        <NameValue> 
          <FirstName>TEST3</FirstName> 
          <Surname>TEST3</Surname> 
        </NameValue> 
        <NameValue> 
          <FirstName>TEST5</FirstName> 
          <MiddleName>TEST6</MiddleName> 
          <Surname>TEST7</Surname> 
          <OriginalName>JAB1</OriginalName> 
        </NameValue> 
        <NameValue> 
          <FirstName>HER</FirstName> 
          <MiddleName>HIS</MiddleName> 
          <Surname>LOO</Surname> 
        </NameValue> 
      </Name>
      <Name NameType="c"> 
        <NameValue> 
          <FirstName>CDS</FirstName> 
          <MiddleName>DRE</MiddleName> 
          <Surname>QWE</Surname> 
        </NameValue> 
        <NameValue> 
          <FirstName>CCD</FirstName> 
          <MiddleName>YTD</MiddleName> 
          <Surname>QQA</Surname> 
        </NameValue> 
        <NameValue> 
          <FirstName>DS</FirstName> 
          <Surname>AzDFz</Surname> 
        </NameValue> 
      </Name> 
    </NameDetails> 
  </EMPLOYEE >
</ABCD>
```

Please note that this is just one small record inside one big xml.Each xml would contain similar records around 5000 in number.Similarly there are more than 400 files each ranging about 4MB size approx.

My xmltype query :

```
SELECT t.personid, t.firstname, t.middlename,
           t.surname,t.maidenname,
           replace(replace(t.originalName, '<OriginalName>'),
                   '</OriginalName>', ' ') originalName
    FROM xml_files p,
         XMLTABLE (
          --'ABCD/EMPLOYEE/NameDetails/Name/NameValue'
          'for $i in ABCD/EMPLOYEE/NameDetails/Name/NameValue
           return <row>
                     {$i/../../../@id}
                     {$i/../@NameType}
                     {$i/FirstName}{$i/MiddleName}{$i/OriginalName}
                     {$i/Surname}{$i/MaidenName}
                 </row>'
         PASSING p.filecontent
         COLUMNS
                 personid     NUMBER         PATH '@id',
                 nametypeid   VARCHAR2(255)  PATH '@NameType',
                 firstname    VARCHAR2(4000) PATH 'FirstName',
                 middlename   VARCHAR2(4000) PATH 'MiddleName',
                 surname      VARCHAR2(4000) PATH 'Surname',
                 maidenname   VARCHAR2(4000) PATH 'MaidenName',
                 originalName XMLTYPE        PATH 'OriginalName'
                 ) t;
```

But this is taking too much time to query all those huge data. The resultset of this query would return about millions of rows. 
I tried to index the table using this query :

```
CREATE INDEX myindex_xmlperson on xml_files(filecontent) indextype is xdb.xmlindex 
parameters ('paths(include(ABCD/EMPLOYEE/NameDetails/Name/NameValue))');
```

Index is created but still no improvement with the performance though. It is taking more than 20 minutes to query even a set of 10 similar xml files.Now you can imagine how much will it take to query all those 1000 xml files.
Could someone please suggest me how to improve the 
performance of my database.Since I am new to this I am not sure whether I am doing it in proper way. If there is a better solution please suggest. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few months, and no one has responded to your question.  I don't have a specific answer for you either, but I can at least point you to these additional resources, in case you haven't tried them:

- [Oracle XML DB technetwork site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database-features/xmldb/overview/index.html) -- whitepapers on best practices, docs, etc.
- [Oracle XML DB forum](https://forums.oracle.com/community/developer/english/oracle_database/xml_db) -- followed by XML DB users, product mgt, and developers